# What's going on with address 1NZ9kxxUykiNSe61ZRNPLqWeVHVRnirGry?

Tags: address, raw-transaction, error

Does anyone know what is going on here:

https://blockchain.info/address/1NZ9kxxUykiNSe61ZRNPLqWeVHVRnirGry

As far as I can tell, it looks like the "1NZ9..." address seems to be one one of those which "cannot be decoded"? How did blockchain.info then decide to show this information page on the address? Because, If I do a `getrawtransaction` on the tx shown there, I get no addresses from bitcoind.

And if the address is one of the "cannot be decoded" ones, how come the Total Received and Final Balance fields are 0?

Answer (score 4):

What is happening here is that blockchain.info parser seems not to work well when decoding Pay-to-multisig scripts (**P2MS**).

All the outputs but last two contain Pay-to-multisig scripts as ScriptPubKey (1-3 Multisig for all but the very last one, that is 1-2 Multisig). The last two are normal Pay-to-PubkeyHash (**P2PKH**).

If you check the information in [blockr.io](http://btc.blockr.io/tx/info/493dde8af86c6d9a451524f0ac8e104e903fc93b7d1f4a758399cc6953b9ec33) for example, you will see it correctly displayed.

You can also check the decoded raw transaction to find it out. Here you have an example of one of the outputs:

```
"asm":"1 8322e509a68669409750b06abef89e48423d21c0089efcc211261c16e8f0a413a693bdee97ca3bd3424eb6247bc235a8d49d77cde681093a4824e462a9ea9610ed b72f5174d4946b456da718db0eb1e852a67544c67e6041f1eb6156bae1b1d788614d89542274f46f0100389a6b40f5158dab5da9870b3447b65e8d003665d0e969 db99614d616506661872851a2786ec296ca73dbab8dbf100c21ef2e80be79eb5d916ab3b3b29ec6e5dcda45a405c155655fe380d979877e53b2f1417a744ebf142 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG"
```

Notice how the structure of the script is: `OP_1 <Public_Key0><Public_Key1>...<Public_KeyN-1> OP_3 OP_CHECK_MULTISIG`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks! Is there a way to get to the list of addresses using bitcoind RPC?

Comment: What do you mean by the list of addresses?

Comment: The result of getrawtransaction for this type of tx includes (in the outputs array) the bitcoin amount but not the output address.

Comment: Sorry, I've been out a few days. This also depends on the decoder you are using to analyse the raw transaction you get from getrawtransaction. For example, blockchain.info (https://blockchain.info/decode-tx), or blockr.io (https://blockr.io/tx/push) do not provide the information about addresses in P2MS transaction, you can only see the collection of public keys inside the script. However, blockcypher (https://live.blockcypher.com/bcy/decodetx/) does.